# Convert bitmap from 16bpp to 8bpp in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, windows, image

I have a Bitmap with 16bpp. I want to convert that image in my ASP.NET side in a 8bpp image.

I tried a lot of options which I found in the internet but nothing works for me.

I also tried that way: [C# Converting 32bpp image to 8bpp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355135/c-sharp-converting-32bpp-image-to-8bpp)

But if I want to save the file, I get the following error:

Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException: A generic error occurred in GDI+.

```
Line 278:                    System.Drawing.Image img2 = Convert(bm_resize);//byteArrayToImage(gray);
Line 279:                    
Line 280:                    img2.Save(helper+"grey2.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
Line 281:                }
Line 282:
```

Is there any correct way for my problem?

Full Code:

```
System.Drawing.Image img2 = Convert(bm_resize);
img2.Save(path+"test.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);


public static System.Drawing.Image Convert(Bitmap oldbmp)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            oldbmp.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Gif);
            ms.Position = 0;
            return System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
        }
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Loading an image from a stream without keeping the stream open](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845456/loading-an-image-from-a-stream-without-keeping-the-stream-open)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by disposing the memory stream before the image is saved.

I believe GDI+ requires the memory stream to persist while you are still working with an Image created from the memory stream.

See the [Microsoft Support article.](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;814675)

Comment: @user694501 - Where is your answer that you'd like me to look at?

Answer (score 0):

I use a little helper function to create 1 bpp monochrome bitmaps in .NET. Check out this link, it also works great for 8 bpp

http://www.wischik.com/lu/programmer/1bpp.html

hope this could help!

Answer (score 0):

[AForge.Net](http://www.aforgenet.com/) has a good collection of free (under Lesser GPL License) routines for such changes and a lot more. Conversion of 16bpp to 8bpp is as simple as [this](http://www.aforgenet.com/aforge/framework/docs/html/87465fa3-c7d0-7df9-382d-245461f48318.htm).