# Converting 32bpp Black and white image to 8bpp Indexed in c#

Tags: c#, grayscale

I have an bitmap which I use graphics function to draw a curve on. The graphics function does not work with 8bpp indexed. After I drew the bitmap, I want to convert it to grayscale 8bpp. However, when I use conversion tools (aforge, clone(), and even some others) they all return a solid black image. These tools work for images with color just fine. But I have a black and white image in 32bpp and I want the image perserved but in a 8bpp format. Is there anyway to do this?

I'm taking this approach because I have a very complicated curve that needs to be scalable. However, I need the image to transform into a double[] to use other tools such as chamfer matching to do additional image processing.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Converting 32bpp image to 8bpp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355135/c-sharp-converting-32bpp-image-to-8bpp)

Comment: The algorithm should be simple: scale the 32 bit numbers to 8 bit numbers.  The easiest way that I can think of to do that is just to take the eight highest-ordered bits of each 32 bit number.  It goes without saying that you're going to lose significant shading detail.